# Double of each message in Skype Web SDK

Tags: skypedeveloper

I have been using Skype Web SDK for sometime now. However even after using the same code given in the sample, I'm getting 2 of each messages that I post when I have signed-in. Anything to used in code to restrict this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to mine, you can find here what I have done to handle it : https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/issues/11

Basically the message is first in a "pending" state and then in the "succeeded" state. So it appears twice.
That's why you want to add a condition on the status like this one :

```
else if (message.direction() == 'Outgoing' && message.status() === "Succeeded")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by two event listeners attached to the "added" event. I would double check that each message is doubled indeed: `app.toJSON()` returns a snapshot of the app which can be inspected in the dev console - there you could find the `activityItems` array and see if there are dups in it.

Comment: Actually, I think I know why you're getting two events. When the SDK sends a message, it immediately adds it to the collection with the current local timestamp: `message.timestamp() == new Date`. However when the server confirms that the message has been sent, it also gives a server timestamp for the message. The SDK wants to keep messages ordered by the timestamps, so it reinserts the message into the collection. This is why you see one `removed` event followed by one `added` event. Consider handling `removed` events in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that antonkh mentions above is the reason for the duplicate messages. This has been fixed to only reinsert the message (in order to preserve ordering by timestamp) if the timestamp actually changes enough to require sorting. In most cases this means there won't be a change to message order so you should not see duplicate messages any more.